# remove chars in string except last

Tags: c#, string, linq, optimization

I'm tring to remove the char '.' from a string except the last occurrence; for example the string

```
12.34.56.78
```

should became

```
123456.78
```

I'm using this loop:

```
while (value != null && value.Count(c => c == '.') > 1)
 {
   value = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf('.')) + value.Substring(value.IndexOf('.') + 1);
 }
```

I wonder if there is a cleaner way (maybe using linq?) to do this whitout an explicit loop?

(I know there is a very similar question but is about perl and things are quite different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that way:

1. search for the last '.' ;
2. substring [0 .. indexOfLastDot] ;
3. remove in place any '.' of the substring
4. concatenate the substring with the rest of the original string, [indexOfLastDot .. remaining]

OR

1. search for the last '.'
2. for each enumerated char of the string
3. if it’s a '.' and i ≠ indexOfLastDot, remove it

Comment: I would be better to provide code examples (at least pseudo code) instead of explaining what you would do.

Comment: I understand, the first solution is neater for me

Answer (score 5):

```
int lastIndex = value.LastIndexOf('.');
if (lastIndex > 0)
{
    value = value.Substring(0, lastIndex).Replace(".", "")
        + value.Substring(lastIndex);
}
```

Comment: Neater than mine, I overcomplicated it for some reason... +1

Comment: it's the same as @skp answer

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a mixture of `string` methods and Linq:

```
string str = "12.34.56.78";
Char replaceChar = '.';
int lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf(replaceChar);
if (lastIndex != -1)
{
    IEnumerable<Char> chars = str
        .Where((c, i) => c != replaceChar || i == lastIndex);
    str = new string(chars.ToArray());
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Mk30y8)

Comment: doesn’t C# have `auto`? just curious

Comment: Nice!  I always like using the Select/Where overload that projects the index into the sequence (where appropriate).

Comment: I prefer the skp solution because is usable also with string replacing (not only char), but +1 for the nice solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  var splitResult = v.Split(new char[] { '.' }).ToList();
  var lastSplit = splitResult.Last();
  splitResult.RemoveAt(splitResult.Count - 1);
  var output = string.Join("", splitResult) + "." + lastSplit;
```

I would do it that way. The neatest way isn't always the shortest way.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.  Whether it is "good" or not is another matter.  Note also that there is no error checking.  Might want to check for null or empty string and that the string has at least one `"."` in it.

```
string numbers = "12.34.56.78";
var parts = String.Split(new char [] {'.'});
string newNumbers = String.Join("",parts.Take(parts.Length-1)
                                        .Concat(".")
                                        .Concat(parts.Last());
```

I don't claim that this would have great performance characteristics for long strings, but it does use Linq ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to use loop:

```
    //string val = "12345678";
    string val = "12.34.56.78";
    string ret = val;
    int index = val.LastIndexOf(".");
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        ret = val.Substring(0, index).Replace(".", "") + val.Substring(index);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(ret);
```

Comment: it's the same as @skp answer